# Equivalence between two notions of hyperplanes.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, affine-geometry

I wanted to understand the following statement: to give a hyperplane in an affine space is equivalent to give an affine hyperplane in a vector space over some field $K$. What is the difference between the two hyperplanes and how are they equivalent? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the first definition is synthetic (axiomatic) and this is a statement saying that the hyperplane can be coordinatised? Although such a statement would depend on the axioms used to build the affine space.

Comment: What is your definition of hyperplane?

Comment: It seems like we have two equivalent definitions here that's what I want to understand.. it seems like we talk about "affine hyperplane" and "vector hyperplane"!